# QT 5.7 QML How to control which Control gets the focus within a TabView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

I'd like to arrange for a specific control to get the focus within a `TabView` `Tab`. Its seems that the first one gets the focus regardless of what I do. I have tried setting `focus:false` everywhere else but it doesn't work.

Consider the following code. I have a simple column containing two `RadioButton`s and a `TextField`. I'd like to arrange for the `TextField` to always get focus when the tab is selected, but it always goes to the first `RadioButton`

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 400

    TabView
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Tab { title: "tab1"; sourceComponent: foo }
        Tab { title: "tab2"; sourceComponent: foo }
    }

    Component
    {
        id: foo
        ColumnLayout
        {
            spacing: 32
            ExclusiveGroup { id: optionGroup }

            RadioButton
            {
                // i always get the focus!!
                exclusiveGroup: optionGroup
                text: "Click me"
                activeFocusOnPress: true
                focus: false
            }

            RadioButton
            {
                exclusiveGroup: optionGroup
                text: "No, click me!"
                activeFocusOnPress: true
                focus: false
            }

            TextField
            {
                // but i want the focus
                placeholderText: "type here"
                focus: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Press "tab2" to see this,

[image]

I tried forcing within `TabView` by adding,

`onCurrentIndexChanged: getTab(currentIndex).item.forceActiveFocus()`

But it makes no difference.

I've read the explanation of focus but it hasn't helped in this case.

Thanks for any suggestion or help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bug. Try [Qt Quick Controls 2.0](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html) instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 400

    header: TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("tab1")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("tab2")
        }
    }

    StackLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex

        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            spacing: 32

            ButtonGroup {
                id: optionGroup
                buttons: columnLayout.children
            }

            RadioButton {
                text: "Click me"
            }

            RadioButton {
                text: "No, click me!"
            }

            TextField {
                placeholderText: "type here"
                focus: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hoped you wouldn't say that :-) A factored this problem from a body of controls 1 code that i'm reluctant to change. I'll try your answer, however, and see if I can mix in some Controls 2 to fix it. thanks.

Comment: This is the answer. You're right, it's superior to use a `StackLayout` I never really liked `TabView` because `Tab`s are loaders. I'm using Controls1 inside the StackLayout and it works fine. Thanks.